# Spring Data Rest exposing unintended HTTP methods

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I defined the following `RestRepository` to expose only `GET /cars`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Car, String> {
    @RestResource
    List<Car> findAll();
}
```

I also put the following annotation to expose only annotated repositories:

```
spring.data.rest.detection-strategy=annotated
```

Everything works well when I call `GET /cars`, but if I call `PATCH /cars/test` I get the following exception (with related 500 status code):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Repository doesn't have a find-one-method declared!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.lambda$invokeFindById$1(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:143) 
    ...
```

Instead, if I call `DELETE /cars/test`, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed (which seems more correct).

Is this a bug or the intended behaviour for Spring Data Rest? If that's intended, how could `PATCH` be gracefully disabled?